# An [esperante] tag for questions written mostly or entirely in Esperanto?

Tags: discussion

It would allow these questions to be easily filtered in or out of searches, for example.

Comment: Why not create it yourself? It **is** a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

I can appreciate the desire to highlight these posts, but using tags for purposes *other* than describing the subject of the post is called "meta tagging" and we explicitly try to avoid using tags like that on these sites. You can read about the problems of meta tags and how to spot them in this blog post:

[**The Death of Meta Tags**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

The justification for avoiding meta tags has held up well over the years. In my experience, those reasons are probably more true than ever.

Comment: the blog post talks about tags where the meaning is subjective. specifying the language a question is written in, is anything but subjective. can't be more objective than that. so the question i would look at is: is there a good reason to filter questions by this tag. there are no good reasons to flter for questions based on the subjective tags mentioned in the blog post, but i think a case can be made that filtering for questions written in esperanto should be possible.

Comment: The reasons mentioned in the blog post don't apply at all to the proposed tag "esperante". I think the proposed tag is a great idea.

Comment: The blog post talks about tags that are used for purposes ***other*** than describing the subject of the post.

Comment: Just because the proposed tag shares a feature with the tags discussed in the blog post doesn't mean that the arguments put forward in the blog post apply to the proposed tag as well. They don't.

Answer (score 6):

I absolutely think that we should have the proposed [esperante] tag. It will make it easier for contributers who cannot or do not want to respond in English to find the questions written in Esperanto. For example, as a member of the Akademio de Esperanto, I am planning to invite the other members to contribute to the Esperanto StackExchange, as their know-how can lead to very high-quality answers. But as some of them might not feal very comfortable answering in English, it would be great if I could show them the link to the questions tagged as [esperante], so that those who whish to do so can concentrate on answering these questions in Esperanto.

Robert Cartaino argued against the tag based on the fact that it is a meta tag. The link that he claims to contain arguments against meta tags only has arguments against special kinds of meta tags that don't carry over to the proposed [esperante] tag. So no good arguments against this tag have been put forward.

Answer (score -1):

[esperante](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esperante) would not say anything about the subject of the question, but rather the language used to write it.

I understand it could be used to filter the questions written in Esperanto, but since there aren't other language Stack Exchange sites using a similar tag, I don't see why we should use it. It is not that difficult to find the questions asked in Esperanto, from the list of questions.

> [image: screenshot]